# Short horror story: a young man has a piece of paper with a curse planted in his pocket

Tags: story-identification, horror

I recall this story having to do with a young man who has a cursed piece of paper secretly placed in his pocket by an evil magic man.

Comment: Your question is too terse. Please add more details. Everything you can remember about the story, when you read it, etc. Was it a book, or a short story, or a movie, or what?

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info); your question needs more detail to fit in our story-identification standards. Every little detail counts!

Answer (score 4):

"[Casting the Runes](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?82288)" by [M. R. James](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._R._James)? The story is available at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/9629) and [LibriVox](https://librivox.org/short-ghost-and-horror-collection-001/), and it has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_the_Runes). It was the basis for the classic horror film [*Curse of the Demon*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050766/).

Here is a paragraph from a review by [Seeks Ghosts](https://seeksghosts.blogspot.com/2014/04/casting-runes.html):

> Karswell manages to track Dunning down and hands him an odd strip of paper. After this, weird things start occurring. Dunning begins to see the name, "John Harrington" in places it should not be and then his household staff is poisoned mysteriously.

Comment: In "Casting the Runes" Dunning is not especially young (he is England's leading authority on alchemy) and the paper with the curse is handed to him rather than "secretly placed in his pocket".